# How do you access the 'request' object (or similar) from custom classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Within my Rails 5 app, I have a custom classes inside `app/services` and I need access to the current subdomain.

Right now, the individual methods may look like this:

```
...
def self.is_valid? req
  blacklist.exclude? req.subdomain
end
```

But this means I need to pass in `request` each time.  This isn't optimal, so I'm wondering how you would access the rails `request` object from within the class.

Comment: Keep in mind that `request` in a controller is just a method that returns the request object, it isn't a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request object is typically only accessible from the controller and the view. You could just pass the request to the methods that need it like any other object (dependency injection), but does your service object really need the whole request object? Why not just pass the subdomain string? In my opinion, service objects shouldn't need to know about the request object as such behavior would probably be better handled from a controller method.

Comment: What if you use a helper method that uses url_for in it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a controller-specific method and will need to passed as an argument anywhere else. This is just the way Rails is build - global variables will be shared between all clients, and controllers are instantiated on a per-client basis. Therefore there is no global "request" object and no built-in way to list all the currently connected users.

Comment: This answer is gibberish to me. It gives no clue how to actually access the request object

Comment: @AnnaNaden The point is that you cannot access `request` from anywhere other than the controller unless you pass it around as an argument. If you can explain where you are trying to use `request` from, possible I can give you more specific advice here.

Comment: And anyway, my (7 year old) answer is basically saying the same thing as Anthony's.